# iPhone: get UILabel width in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone

I have a UITableView with a custom row. On my custom row I have UILAbel with autosizing by width mask, that is why in portrait it has one width and in landscape another.

In my cellForRowAtIndexPath I should get label width:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
        (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UILabel *myLabel = 
    (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    float width = myLabel.frame.size.width;
}
```

And when i run application, everything is fine and width is good. But when I rotate device to landscape, cellForRowAtIndexPath called before UILAbel changed its frame, and I'v got the same width as in portrait. So how to be ? How to get right width when I rotate device ? The one idea that comes on my mind is to reload tableView in didRotateForInterfaceOrientation...Is there any other solutions ? Thanks...

**UPDATE:**

One more thing, when I start application in Landscape mode, width is still like in Portrait. Why ? How to fix that ?

Comment: May be you need to reload table on rotating device ? Yes I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this code with yours. May this will help:

```
    static NSString *iden = @"Setting";
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:iden];

            if (cell == nil)
            {

                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:iden];
                UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
                float xpos = cell.contentView.frame.origin.x ;
                float ypos = cell.contentView.frame.origin.y;       
                float nwidth = cell.contentView.frame.size.width ;
                float nheight = cell.contentView.frame.size.height;
                label.frame = CGRectMake(xpos, ypos, nwidth, nheight);

                label.tag = indexPath.row + 7777;

                [cell.contentView addSubview:label];
    [label release]
        }
      UILabel *labeltagged =(UILabel*) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row+7777];
    float xpos = cell.contentView.frame.origin.x ;
                float ypos = cell.contentView.frame.origin.y;       
                float nwidth = cell.contentView.frame.size.width ;
                float nheight = cell.contentView.frame.size.height;
                labeltagged.frame = CGRectMake(xpos, ypos, nwidth, nheight);

return cell;
```